# What are permitted values for language field in Bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

I need to cite a document that is in other language than my work. I have found a webpage http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~collberg/Teaching/07.231/BibTeX/bibtex.html that mentions `language` field but there is no information how is the language specified.

Does anybody know what are permitted values?

Comment: The `language` field is ignored by most bibliography styles.

Comment: Or it has to be ignored (omitted), see BBT addon for Zotero, which can do that if you export the bib, which can cause a problem in your LaTeX processing in conjunction with babel if things are not harmonic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Load package [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) and use the in `babel` defined language name, for example `english`, `german` for German with old writing rules, `ngerman` for new writing rules.

Add `language = {english},` for each `bib` file entry.

Comment: This is a bad specification gap. People document whatever they come up with in the .bib: English, EN, Eng etc. so you end up with various formats all over. The babel connection makes sense.